# Camera Angle Field Of View

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, camera, devextreme

I am working on **Cordova(Phonegap)** I need to determine Device specific camera Properties. I have been searching on web for a quality period of time. Still not getting any way. Is there any way to determine

1.Vertical-horizontal CAFOV (Camera Angle Field Of View) value,

2.Maximum supported image sizes,

3.Focus mode ,Exposure Value ?.

Any damn help will be appreciated. Thank you.